# SVN : Moved files are redownloaded upon update

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Working with SVN on a project with a lot of large binary files, I've come up with a problem :

I tried to change the folder organisation of major parts of the working copy, using only the builtin TortoiseSVN function to move versionned files within a WC and doing commits after that at the root of the project but when I do an update on another computer, it still seems like it's redownloading every moved files :

It takes a very long time to update and I can see it takes a lot of bandwidth whereas the commit was done in no time, looking like it just needed to send the "order" to move the files and not reupload them (as expected).

I don't think I've encountered the same behaviour on other projects using SVN.

Is it supposed to be this way or is there a solution to avoid redownloading all those files that are already existing in other locations of the working copy ?

**EDIT** : After some further testing, I saw that the log stated the file was copied from the old path but at this time, the file was already deleted on my WC before the new one was copied so I did a test doing a copy + commit and then deleted the old one + commit and the update on another computer and the result was exactly the same (redownloaded everything).

It turns out that even with a simple SVN copy and commit, an update on another computer redowloads the file even if it's present on my disk and the log clearly shows the new file was copied from the old one...
I'm a bit lost on this one !

Thanks,
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use an outdated and unsupported version of TortoiseSVN / Apache Subversion. Read [SVN 1.8 Release Notes | Checkout and update download pristine file data just once](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#pristines).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I was using 1.8 from the start, I updated to 1.9 a few days ago but it didnt change anything, and other people using the repo use various versions from 1.7 to 1.9 with the same problem. Unfortunately, I don't know the server's version and don't have direct access to it...